# Nginx: How to redirect to https, but not for subdomain

Tags: nginx

I would like Nginx to redirect visitors to HTTPS on my top-level domain, but not for certain subdomains (because I don't want to bother adding subdomains to my certificate and its not necessary anyway). What seems to be happening is Nginx is redirecting to HTTPS on my top-level domain as well as for all subdomains despite that I only explicitly put the redirect in the server block for the top-level domain. Below is basically the way I'm doing it:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ...
}

server {
  server_name nossl.example.com;
  listen 80;
}
```

When a user visits http://nossl.example.com, they're forced to use SSL (HTTPS) and consequently get an ugly warning about the certificate. How can I have it not do that?

Comment: Are you using HSTS in your HTTPS configuration? Look to see if you have `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;includeSubDomains";` or something similar.

Comment: No, I don't have anything like that in my config.

Comment: @Paul, I have similiar problem, I am using SSL with HSTS, but header you have mentioned doesn'e exists in my configuration. I am not sure what else to search. Curl and wget is working properly when I am testing.

Comment: @AlanKis Please post a new question and be sure to include your nginx configurations.

Comment: This doesn't look as an nignx problem, not at least in the part of the configuration that you are posting. That configuration should work, and works on my servers

Answer (score 2):

On the nginx SSL config:

Find the the code `add_header Strict-Transport-Security`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ....
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;";
}
```

Please remove the param `includeSubDomains`.
The correct code is :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ....
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
}
```

This will not apply SSL on the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ugly solution I came up with. I added another server block for https://nossl.example.com that redirects to http://nossl.example.com. I think there should be a more elegant solution.

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ...
}

server {
  server_name nossl.example.com;
  listen 80;
}

server {
  server_name nossl.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl;
  return 301 http://nossl.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't work if it is an nginx issue because all that would happen is the following nossl.example.com>301>(ssl)nossl.example.com>301>nossl.example.com and repeat. Can you post the rest of your config to the question. Do you have any services sitting infront of the server?

Comment: @Drifter104 I realized I made a mistake in the last server block. I left out the subdomain. Now there should't be a loop, right?

Comment: You misunderstand. You shouldn't get the behavior from the server blocks in your question. So if you are getting the redirects it is something else that isn't in the config that you have posted. Have you got something like cloudflare or similar inplace

Comment: I'm using Digital Ocean as my host, I'm not using a CDN unless they are.

Comment: You can remove your last server block as it won't fix anything.  You will need a valid certificate for the https domain to get any kind of redirect working from it.  Your 3rd server block is catching the nossl subdomain and your 1st server block will catch everything else (on port 80).  See `default_server` and [how nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more information.